# GCDWebServer Main thread & UI

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, http

I use GCDWebServer for create a simple server where users can download file from document, from a button I show an UIAlertView where there is the IP Address of iphone, then on click I star the server, the problem is there after start of server the UI is blocked, the uialertview not dismiss.

This is my code

```
    if (alertView.tag == 999) {

    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    self.webServer = [[GCDWebServer alloc] init];
    [self.webServer addHandlerForBasePath:@"/" localPath:documentsDir indexFilename:nil cacheAge:3600];
    [self.webServer runWithPort:8080];

    // I try this 2 solution but no one work
    //[self starsServer]
    //[self performSelector:@selector(startServer) onThread:[NSThread mainThread]  withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void) startServer {

[self.webServer start];
```

}

where is the error?

Answer (score 4):

Do not use `-runWithPort:` as it will block the thread. This method should only be used on Mac command line tools.

Just call `-start` after creating the server. This will not block the current thread but start the server in the background. Then you can use Xcode debugger to find out what is happening afterwards that hangs the UI (most likely the current function being executed is not returning).